# Alert in Java Script in Tizen

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app

I have following code in JS :-

```
function allowDigits(evt) {
    debugger;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 46 && evt.srcElement.value.split('.').length > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (charCode !== 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        alert('Enter valid Input');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this I am getting a Alert Box, But after pop up if i give any integer then earlier non integer digit like alphabet is also getting displayed with integer.
Whereas in the code below :-

```
function allowDigits(evt) {
    debugger;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 46 && evt.srcElement.value.split('.').length > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (charCode !== 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am not displaying any alert and this code is working fine.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly on a device. But on Emulator when typing through Laptop KeyBoard it is not Working.